# Cycling through decimal values

Tags: php, math

As part of a PHP project, I have the need of returning the sine value of each value included in an arbitrary interval. Moreover, I also need to be able to set the "scope" of the function, that is, how many decimal places I need to cycle.

Eg: 1 decimal place for interval 1 to 3 included:
1, 1.1, 1.2, ... 2.8, 2.9, 3

2 decimal places for the same interval

1, 1.01, 1.02 ... 2.98, 2.99, 3

Etc... I tried doing it with the "for" cycle, but it would only consider natural numbers.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why is 3 in the first example output but not in the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak the code below code to suit your needs:

```
$start = 1;
$end = 3;
$place = 1;

$step = 1 / pow(10, $place);

for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = round($i + $step, $place))
{
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
2.5
2.6
2.7
2.8
2.9
3
```

Comment: Dejavu: Why is 3 missing in output?^^

Comment: @Nobody: That was just a floating point error. I've updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!! Just one thing, when I raise the number of decimal places to 4-5 it gets extremely slow, is there any way I can make it faster? (I'm running localhost)

Comment: It is in the nature of this, that it gets slower, when you create more values. I would say this already is the fastest approach you can get with php. If you want to be faster you probably need a faster language or a builtin function that maps to a faster language ^^

Comment: Actually, the bottleneck seems to be the output (I didn't check if that's the connection or the editor). Just the loop itself takes about a sec to run here for 5 decimals, but outputting those 200,000 lines and things really stall.